# CKEditor youtube plugin error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I'm using ckeditor with youtube plugin for rails app and I got this errors in console
[image]

15 errors for 15 langs in langs folder.

how to fix this?

config.js

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
  // ... other configuration ...
    config.assets_languages = ['en'];
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;image:Link;link:advanced;link:upload';
    config.linkShowTargetTab = false;
    config.youtube_width = '640';
    config.youtube_height = '480';
    config.extraPlugins = 'youtube';
    CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = [

       ['Bold','Italic','Underline','StrikeThrough','-','Undo','Redo','-','Print'],
       ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
       ['Link','TextColor','BGColor'],
            {name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image','Table','Youtube' ] }
    ] ;

  // ... rest of the original config.js  ...
}
```

**up**

If I open my index page where I list all records or show action on one of the records I got that errors as I showed above)

*this is how I installed the plugin(the folder structure):*

[image]

*application.js*

```
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery.turbolinks   
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**UP2**

**When I move ckeditor directory to public there're no errors. **

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue. Using CKEditor 4.4.6 and youtube plugin 2.0.0. Please provide a working example to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem by removing /lang folder of youtube plugin and manually renaming all the labels of the plugin. This's not how it supposed to work but it works.